# Changing the homebrew editor

Tags: homebrew

I would like to change my HOMEBREW_EDITOR. Sadly I do not have a ~/.bash_profile as I am using a Mac. Instead I have a ~/.zprofile which usually does the job. Now I added HOMEBREW_EDITOR=nano to this profile and typed in source ~/.zprofile but nothing changes. What can I do?
Thanks,
Emil

I was expecting nano to open when typing in brew edit but vim opened again.

Comment: You should use [.zshrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) rather than zprofile.

Comment: You need to `export` the variable, otherwise it is available only to the shell, not also to the processes that the shell starts.

Comment: Thank you for the support, but I did not understand what to do. What does export the variable mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `~/.bash_profile` is unrelated to you using a Mac or not: you can create it if you want. However if you used `~/.zprofile` in the past for such thing indicates you are using Zsh instead of Bash, so your configuration should go in `~/.zprofile` (or `~/.zrc`) rather than `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`).

The part you are missing is the [`export`](https://linuxhint.com/set-environment-variable-zsh/#:%7E:text=To%20set%20environment%20variables%2C%20we%20use%20the%20export%20command) keyword:

```
export HOMEBREW_EDITOR=nano
```

Without `export`, the variable would be set for your shell but wouldn’t be passed to child processes such as Homebrew.